# com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, hibernate

I am unable to create the session factory object. When I put the log statement line by line, code is failing at HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory() method. Can you please help where am I going wrong here ? I am attaching all the relevent code which I am using.

I think the error is misleading as it suggests the error as 
1. "ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.Type" inspite the availability of asm-1.5.3.jar.
2. com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl

All the hibernate 3 related jar files are in classpath
Below are the code

**1. tsrHibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">Template-DS</property> 
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="SetBigStringTryClob">true</property>
        <property name="batch_size">0</property>

        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/CommonRequestsTemplates.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Tsr.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Sequence.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/lovvalues.hbm.xml" /> 
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Asset.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/AssetEnvAssociation.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Environment.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/AutomationEnvAuthentication.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/AutomationContentType.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Language.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/AutomationEnvContents.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/Customer.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/ScoreIsrvceFileUpload.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/ibm/aodt/isrvce/hibernate/mappings/AutomationLookup.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**2. CommonRequestsTemplates.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping 
    package="com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.hibernate.mappings"  default-lazy="false">

    <class name="com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.hibernate.mappings.CommonRequestsTemplates" table="COMMON_REQUESTS_TEMPLATES">
            <id name="id">
            <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="parentId" type="int">
            <column name="parent_id" length="4" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="templateName" type="string">
            <column name="template_name" length="150" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="templateId" type="string">
            <column name="template_id" length="10" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sortOrder" type="string">
            <column name="sort_order" length="10" not-null="false"/>
        </property>

        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="10" not-null="false"/>
        </property> 

    </class>
            <sql-query name="commonReqTempQuery">
            <return alias="commonRequestsTemplates" class="com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.hibernate.mappings.CommonRequestsTemplates"/>

            SELECT  id  AS {commonRequestsTemplates.id},
                GET_TRANSLATION_LOVVALUES(template_name,:locale) AS {commonRequestsTemplates.templateName},
                parent_id AS {commonRequestsTemplates.parentId},
                template_id AS {commonRequestsTemplates.templateId},
                sort_order AS {commonRequestsTemplates.sortOrder},
                status AS {commonRequestsTemplates.status}
                FROM common_requests_templates crt, app_org ao
                WHERE  (crt.status = 'Active' OR crt.status like '%Autom%') 
                AND crt.app_id = ao.app_id 
                AND ao.org_id = :orgId
                ORDER BY crt.sort_order

        </sql-query>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

**3. CrtDAO.java**

```
package com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.hibernate.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.utils.TsrDaoConstants;


public class CrtDAO {

    public static String hibernateLocation = "tsrHibernate.cfg.xml";

    public static List findByOrg(String orgId, String userLocale) {
        try
        {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession( hibernateLocation);
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            List crtList = session.getNamedQuery("commonReqTempQuery")
            .setString("orgId",orgId)
            .setString("locale",userLocale)
            .list();
            tx.commit();
            return crtList;

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally{
            HibernateUtil.closeSession( hibernateLocation);
        }

    }

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( CrtDAO.class );
}
```

---

**4. HibernateUtil.java**

```
package com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * @author Administrator
 *
 * TODO To change the template for this generated type comment go to
 * Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style - Code Templates
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static HashMap sessionFactories;

    static{
        sessionFactories = new HashMap();
    }

    private static void createSessionFactory(String configFileName){
        sessionFactories.put(configFileName, new Configuration().configure(configFileName).buildSessionFactory());    // Error while invoking buildSessionFactory
    }

    private static final ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();

    public static Session currentSession(String configFileName) throws HibernateException {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session currentSession = null;
        HashMap sessions = null;

        synchronized(threadLocal){

            sessions = (HashMap) threadLocal.get();

            if(sessions != null){
                currentSession = (Session) sessions.get(configFileName);
            }           

            if(currentSession == null){

                sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) sessionFactories.get(configFileName);

                if(sessionFactory == null){
                    createSessionFactory(configFileName);
                    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) sessionFactories.get(configFileName);
                }

                currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();

                if(sessions == null){
                    sessions = new HashMap();
                }

                sessions.put(configFileName, currentSession);
                threadLocal.set(sessions);
            }
        }
        return currentSession;
    }

    public static void closeSession(String configFileName) throws HibernateException {
        HashMap sessions = null;
        synchronized(threadLocal){
            sessions = (HashMap)threadLocal.get();
            Session currentSession = (Session)sessions.get(configFileName);
            sessions.remove(configFileName);

            if(sessions.isEmpty()){
                sessions = null;
                threadLocal.set(null);
            }

            if(currentSession != null){
                currentSession.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**5. ErrorLog.txt**

```
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl &#40;initialization failure&#41;
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:702)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm._jsp._CommonRequestsTemplates._jspService(_CommonRequestsTemplates.java:516)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.isrvce.login.client.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:605 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:262)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:353)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl (initialization failure)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:620 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1055)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util.HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util.HibernateUtil.currentSession(HibernateUtil.java:55)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.hibernate.dao.CrtDAO.findByOrg(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.corio.tsr.implementations.CommonRequestsTemplatesDAO.getTemplates(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.corio.tsr.implementations.CommonRequestsTemplatesDAO.getTopLevelParents(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm._jsp._CommonRequestsTemplates._jspService(_CommonRequestsTemplates.java:213)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  ... 38 more
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.objectweb.asm.Type
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at net.sf.cglib.core.TypeUtils.parseType(TypeUtils.java:180)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.<clinit>(KeyFactory.java:66)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1055)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util.HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.aodt.isrvce.util.HibernateUtil.currentSession(HibernateUtil.java:55)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.corio.tsr.implementations.ReqSearchDAO.searchReqs(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at com.corio.tsr.implementations.actions.portlets.ReqSearchAction.buildNormalContext(Unknown Source)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.modules.actions.portlets.JspPortletAction.buildNormalContext(JspPortletAction.java:116)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.modules.actions.portlets.GenericMVCAction.doPerform(GenericMVCAction.java:169)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.modules.actions.portlets.GenericMVCAction.perform(GenericMVCAction.java:126)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.turbine.modules.ActionLoader.exec(ActionLoader.java:122)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.portal.portlets.GenericMVCPortlet.buildContent(GenericMVCPortlet.java:276)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.portal.portlets.GenericMVCPortlet.getContent(GenericMVCPortlet.java:207)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:636 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.jetspeed.portal.security.portlets.PortletWrapper.getContent(PortletWrapper.java:115)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:652 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:652 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:652 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[1/25/17 5:54:26:652 PST] 00000040 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
```

Comment: The same code is working fine in WAS6.0 and WAS6.1. While migrating the application from WAS6.1 to WAS7.0 we encountered the above issue. WAS7.0 doesnt seem to have any problem with Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You need the class org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.class in your project. Try to import hibernate-3.0.5.jar in your classpath.

Comment: @Dekkar, hibernate-3.0.5.jar is already in the classpath. But along with hibernate-3.0.5.jar, we also have hibernate.jar and hibernate3.jar in the classpath. Will this create any problem ?

Comment: Yes it will, may cause compilation errors in the deployement. Keep only one hibernate.jar, in your classpath. And try to re-compile and deploy again.

Comment: After removing the other two hibernate jars from classpath, now we have a different error as below : 
'com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.HibernateException
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:702)
at com.ibm._jsp._CommonRequestsTemplates._jspService(_CommonRequestsTemplates.java:516)'

Comment: Check if you jars have been deployed in your server . If it's not in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your Dynamic Web
Project, you might need to go to the project's Java EE Module
Dependencies property page (select Properties from the project's
context menu) and tell it to include the jar

Comment: I fixed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.HibernateException.
But now I have new exception as below :
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/SAXReader
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/SAXReader

One fix is opening up some other new issue. Am I on the right track ? Is this purely an issue with dependent jar files ?

Comment: Yes it is. All the errors that youre getting is about jars. Check that the error points to classes of libraries.Now the error that youre getting is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/SAXReader, check if you have this jar in the classpath => dom4j-1.3.jar

Comment: Sometimes happens that when we are migrating some apps to a different version of a server, we need some libraries to our new server. Understand that every version of a server, have some libraries and other version have others. Sorry for my english level.

Comment: Added dom4j-1.3.jar but still same error exists. Any other changes required ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the jar files but the folder name in which all the jars were present. May be **WAS7** does not consider space as part of folder name. We renamed jar folder name used by the shared library from "SPRING HIBERNATE AND ADAMS" to "SPRING_HIBERNATE_AND_ADAMS" (space replaced with underscore) and everything started working fine.